# PlayFramework 2.0.x -> 2.1-RC migration

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.1

In my program on Play 2.0.4 I had this piece of code:

```
val channel = Enumerator.imperative[JsValue](onStart = self ! NotifyJoin(username))
```

and now it says that `imperative` is deprecated, and the API says that I should use `unicast` or `broadcast` instead. I tend to use `unicast` since in my code the `channel` was unicast. So I make like

```
val channel = Concurrent.unicast[JsValue](onStart = self ! NotifyJoin(username))
```

But it does not work.. looks like that `unicast` wants something else. I cannot figure it out - there is no more info in the API... does anyone know what to do here?

**UPDATE:**

Started a discussion in Play Framework user group. Turns out to be a pretty common problem among developers, who are knew to the paradigm. Will hope the documentation is going to be improved.

Comment: i think play framework 2.*.* not good at documentation when we compare it with 1.x.x versions.

Answer (score 3):

The API for `Concurrent.unicast` is:

```
unicast[E](onStart: (Channel[E]) ⇒ Unit, onComplete: ⇒ Unit, onError: (String, Input[E]) ⇒ Unit): Enumerator[E]
```

The API for `Concurrent.broadcast` is:

```
broadcast[E]: (Enumerator[E], Channel[E])
```

You can get to the API in your app at:

```
http://localhost:9000/@documentation/api/scala/index.html#play.api.libs.iteratee.Concurrent$
```

Comment: Yeah, I saw this on the website. Too bad, it does not say anything on where I get the `Channel[E]`, or the `Enumerator[E]` and does not really explain how the thing works. Actually, at the time I was on the API page, there were just these two signatures. But this is not much more help than Eclipse provides by default, in its autocompletion suggestions. I am just trying to make point that some explanation is worth.

Comment: `broadcast` returns a tuple with an `Enumerator[E]` and a `Channel[E]`.  Is that not what you need?

Comment: Haha, call me what you want, but I am totally new to this kind of API, so I just want a good textual explanation, not the signatures. Anyway, there is already a thread in the Play Framework usergroup about this... turns out to be that many ppl are new into this area.

Comment: I know what you mean.  Code examples are pretty lacking for this stuff.  :(

Answer (score 0):

Example of using Unicast:

```
// here is an enumerator that returns a chunk to the channel
val outEnumerator = Concurrent.unicast[JsValue] { channel =>
    val data = Json.obj("data" -> 12345)
    channel.push(data)
}
```

An alternative to using the old Enumerator.imperative is to use the generateM:

```
val out = Enumerator.generateM[JsValue] {
    Promise.timeout( {
        Some(Json.obj("data" -> 12345))
    }, 100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS )
}
```

Here, we generate a repeating value using a timeout. This enumerator repeats forever, although generateM allows you to return None to indicate when done.